# Problema al realizar ahorcado en C. ¿Cómo seguir, qué me falta?

Tags: c

Me han mandado crear un ahorcado en C y creo que voy bien encaminado, pero ahora me he quedado estancado y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

El error que tengo es que no me muestra en pantalla la opción de poner la letra. ¿Por qué ocurre esto y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 0x100
#define CANTIDAD(x) (sizeof ( (x) ) / sizeof(char *) - 1)

const char *palabra[]={"melifluo","inefable","sonambulo","serendipia","limerencia","etereo","arrebol","irisdencia","epifania","luminiscencia","soledad","aurora","efimero","incandescencia","elocuencia","efervescencia",NULL};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    printf("\nBienvenido al ahorcado\n");

        printf("\nTienes 6 intentos \n");

    char adivinado[MAX], letErroneas[MAX];
    const char *elegida;
    char letra;
    int aleatoria, numLet = 0, Errors = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));
    aleatoria = rand() % CANTIDAD(palabra);
    elegida = palabra[aleatoria];

    bzero(adivinado,MAX);
    for (int i=0; i<(int) strlen(elegida); i++)
        adivinado[i] = '-';

    adivinado[0] = ' ';

    printf("\t\n%s\n", adivinado);
//  printf("\t%s\n", elegida); tapando este printf evitamos que salga la palabra seleccionada


    while(numLet > 0 && Errors <5){
        printf("Mete una letra: ");
        scanf(" %c",&letra);

    int anterior = numLet;
    for(int i=0 ; i<strlen(elegida); i++){
        if(letra == elegida[i]){
            adivinado[i] = letra;
            numLet --;
        }
    }
    if(anterior == numLet)
        letErroneas[Errors++] = letra;

    printf(" %s\n",adivinado);
    printf(" Llevas %i errores \n Te quedan %i errores por realizar",Errors,5-Errors);
    if(Errors > 0)
        printf(" Has dicho estas letras erroneas: %s \n",letErroneas);



    if(numLet == 0)
        printf("\n GANASTES !");
    else if(Errors == 5)
        printf("\n Perdistes !");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes; primero, un par de consejos, con ánimo constructivo:

```
bzero( adivinado, MAX );
```

NO es portable, y está marcada como obsoleta. Deberías de utilizar `memset( adivinado, 0, MAX );`

Luego, haces

```
for (int i=0; i<(int) strlen(elegida); i++)
  adivinado[i] = '-';

  adivinado[0] = ' ';
```

¿ porqué no empiezas el `for` por 1 ?, total, luego asignas el `adivinado[0]`.

```
for (int i=1; i<(int) strlen(elegida); i++)
```

Pasamos al problema:

```
int aleatoria, numLet = 0, Errors = 0;
...
while(numLet > 0 && Errors <5){
```

Con esto, **nunca** entrarás al `while( )`
Deduzco (un comentario hubiera estado bien) que `numLet` es el número de letras **sin adivinar** de la palabra elegida, así que deberías de hacer

```
elegida = palabra[aleatoria];

numLet = strlen( elegida );
....
while( numLet & Errors <5 ) {
...
```

Con eso, asignas el valor correcto.

Por último, haces

```
  ...
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

Así, estas colocando el `return` **dentro** del `while`, con lo que tan solo ejecutas el bucle **1** vez.

Saca ese `return` de ahí, y ponlo justo antes del paréntesis de cierre de `main( )`:

```
  ...
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**EDITO**

Por los comentarios, parece ser que olvidé algo, o el autor de la pregunta hizo alguna modificación posterior. Muestro el código final, al completo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 0x100
#define CANTIDAD(x) (sizeof ( (x) ) / sizeof(char *) - 1)

const char *palabra[]={"melifluo","inefable","sonambulo","serendipia","limerencia","etereo","arrebol","irisdencia","epifania","luminiscencia","soledad","aurora","efimero","incandescencia","elocuencia","efervescencia",NULL};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    printf("\nBienvenido al ahorcado\n");

        printf("\nTienes 6 intentos \n");

    char adivinado[MAX], letErroneas[MAX];
    const char *elegida;
    char letra;
    int aleatoria, numLet, Errors = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));
    aleatoria = rand() % CANTIDAD(palabra);
    elegida = palabra[aleatoria];

    numLet = strlen( elegida );

    bzero(adivinado,MAX);
    for (int i=0; i<(int) strlen(elegida); i++)
        adivinado[i] = '-';

    adivinado[0] = ' ';

    printf("\t\n%s\n", adivinado);
//  printf("\t%s\n", elegida); tapando este printf evitamos que salga la palabra seleccionada


    while(numLet && Errors <5){
        printf("Mete una letra: ");
        scanf(" %c",&letra);

    int anterior = numLet;
    for(int i=0 ; i<strlen(elegida); i++){
        if(letra == elegida[i]){
            adivinado[i] = letra;
            numLet --;
        }
    }
    if(anterior == numLet)
        letErroneas[Errors++] = letra;

    printf(" %s\n",adivinado);
    printf(" Llevas %i errores \n Te quedan %i errores por realizar",Errors,5-Errors);
    if(Errors > 0)
        printf(" Has dicho estas letras erroneas: %s \n",letErroneas);



    if(numLet == 0)
        printf("\n GANASTES !");
    else if(Errors == 5)
        printf("\n Perdistes !");


    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

En mis pruebas, funciona correcto.
Un detalle para el autor: no tienes en cuenta si el usuario introduce la misma letra más de una vez.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda , pero ahora haciendo lo que me dices, cuando pongo una letra bien se acaba el programa y tendría que seguir poniendo letras asta que acertara la palabra o fallara mas de 5 errores.

Comment: En mis pruebas funciona perfecto. ¿ has cambiado algo mas ?

Answer (score 0):

Inicias *numeroLet* en 0, al momento de entrar a la condición del while al no cumplirse que es mayor a 0, entonces nunca entra al while ya que esa condición es falsa.

Inicia *numeroLet* en 1

Comment: Gracias, por la ayuda, pero al poner numLet 1 , luego solo me deja meter 1 letra y se sale el programa.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esta lìnea:

```
int aleatoria, numLet = 0, Errors = 0;
```

Por esta:

```
int aleatoria, numLet = 1, Errors = 0;
```

Comment: Hola @user3143416. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte! ¿Podrías comentar con un poco más de detalle de qué forma es que este código responde a la pregunta? La idea es sumar respuestas al sitio con la mayor calidad posible. Pensemos en alguien que recién se inicia en esto y se encuentra con este mismo problema, buscando resolver y entender por qué o cómo funcionan las cosas. Quizás una muy breve descripción haría toda la diferencia.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que con scanf, lee el carácter y deja en el buffer \n, para solucionarlo, puedes colocar:

```
Letra = getchar(); // leer caracter
getchar(); // tomar el /n
```

Comment: Aunque este comportamiento es variable entre las plataforma de sistema operativo.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente el código queda así, muchas gracias a todos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 0x100
#define CANTIDAD(x) (sizeof ( (x) ) / sizeof(char *) - 1)

const char *palabra[]={"melifluo","inefable","sonambulo","serendipia","limerencia","etereo","arrebol","irisdencia","epifania","luminiscencia","soledad","aurora","efimero","incandescencia","elocuencia","efervescencia",NULL};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  printf("\nBienvenido al ahorcado\n");
  printf("\nTienes 6 intentos \n");

  char adivinado[MAX], letErroneas[MAX];
  const char *elegida;
  char letra;
  int aleatoria, numLet = 1, Errors = 0;

  srand(time(NULL));
  aleatoria = rand() % CANTIDAD(palabra);
  elegida = palabra[aleatoria];

  numLet = strlen( elegida );

  bzero(adivinado,MAX);
  for (int i=0; i<(int) strlen(elegida); i++)
    adivinado[i] = '-';

  adivinado[0] = ' ';

  printf("\t\n%s\n", adivinado);
//  printf("\t%s\n", elegida); tapando este printf evitamos que salga la palabra seleccionada

  while(numLet && Errors <5){
    printf("Mete una letra: ");
    scanf(" %c",&letra);

    int anterior = numLet;
    for(int i=0 ; i<strlen(elegida); i++){
      if(letra == elegida[i]){
        adivinado[i] = letra;
        numLet --;
      }
    }
    if(anterior == numLet)
      letErroneas[Errors++] = letra;

    printf(" %s\n",adivinado);
    printf(" Llevas %i errores \n Te quedan %i errores por realizar",Errors,5-Errors);
    if(Errors > 0)
      printf(" Has dicho estas letras erroneas: %s \n",letErroneas);

    if(numLet == 0)
      printf("\n GANASTES !");
    else if(Errors == 5)
      printf("\n Perdistes !");
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```